# How to create react form with dynamic fields fetched from api

Tags: reactjs, forms

I want to create a react form with dynamic inputs, those inputs are fetched from server.

I fetched the data and I have displayed the form but the problem was how to get the values of the inputs with the onChange method

Answer (score 0):

Use a Usestate hook and assign the value fetched from the API there

eg:-

```
const [value,setValue] = useState(fetch());

function fetch(){

//API call...
//return the value got from the API
}
```

Now in form input field you can use this as value and have an onChange and change the `value` state.

eg:-

```
<input value={value.name} name="name" onChange={(e)=>handlechange(e)} />
```

in handlechange :

```
const handlechange = (e)=>{
const {name,value} = e.target;
setValue({...value,[name]:value});
};
```

After this you can have an `useEffect`, which will `POST` the value to the backend using another API for every changes made in the `form`

Here is the code sandbox link:https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-moon-wxp4w7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thank you your response helped me go through my problem. But for my case even the names of the inputs are fetched from the api.

Answer (score 0):

after some researches on stackoverflow here is my solution:

```
const [fields, setFields] = useState([{field:"", value:""}]);

useEffect(()=>{
 if(fetchedData){
  setFields(fetchedData.map((item)=>{
    var rObj ={field:"", value:""};
    rObj["field"] = item;
    return rObj;
  }));
 }
},[fetchedData])

const handleChange = ( index, event ) => {
 if(fields) {
  let data = [...fields];
  data[index]["value"] = event.target.value;
  setFields(data);
 }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////
{fetchedData.map((field, index) => (
   <div key={index}>
     <input 
       required
       type="text" 
       name={field}
       value={fields.field}
       placeholder= {field}
       onChange={event=>{handleChange(index, event)}}
      />
    </div>
   ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code:

```
const GenerateForm() => {
  const [formInputs, setFormInputs] = useState({});

  const handleInputChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormInputs({ ...formInputs, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <form>
      {formData.map(input => {
        if (input.type === "text" || input.type === "number") {
          return (
            <div key={input.name}>
              <label htmlFor={input.name}>{input.label}:</label>
              <input
                type={input.type}
                name={input.name}
                value={formInputs[input.name] || ""}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
          );
        } else if (input.type === "select" || input.type === "radio") {
          return (
            <div key={input.name}>
              <label>{input.label}:</label>
              {input.options.map(option => (
                <div key={option.value}>
                  <input
                    type={input.type}
                    name={input.name}
                    value={option.value}
                    checked={formInputs[input.name] === option.value}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                  />
                  {option.label}
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          );
        }
        return null;
      })}
    </form>
  );
}

const formData = [
  {
    name: "firstName",
    label: "First Name",
    type: "text"
  },
  {
    name: "lastName",
    label: "Last Name",
    type: "text"
  },
  {
    name: "age",
    label: "Age",
    type: "number"
  },
  {
    name: "gender",
    label: "Gender",
    type: "radio",
    options: [
      {
        value: "male",
        label: "Male"
      },
      {
        value: "female",
        label: "Female"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "country",
    label: "Country",
    type: "select",
    options: [
      {
        value: "india",
        label: "India"
      },
      {
        value: "usa",
        label: "USA"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```